# Handling Detail updates in Master-Detail view in Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, bindingsource, tableadapter

I have an application which has a Mainform that has 2 panels using a splitter. The top panel is a form that has the binding navigator, dataset, bindingsource, tableadapters..

The bottom panel is a form as well. It's just a datagridview basically. I pass the bindingsource from the top form, into the bottom form when the Mainform loads.

The bottom form takes the bindingsource, and uses a relationship (between two tables) for it's own datasource member.

Viewing the data works great.

When I update data in the master, i capture it when the user is navigating off the record. I use bindingsource.EndEdit(), DataSet.HasChanges() to verify and then tableadapter.update to write the data before navigating to the next record.

That also works great.

Now, how do I capture and write data in the detail(bottom) form? all it has is the bindingsource passed in.

I have a partially working solution, where the top form actually uses a second tableadapter.update statement to write the the child table.. but it seems to take 2 record navigations for that to work. (at which point the data is actually updated correctly though)

Any high level better ways to work all this?
thanks
R

Comment: it appears the write gets caught by the top form as soon as i navigate to the next record - IF I change records on the bottom detail form after making the change.  But if I stay on the changed record, and navigate to the next one on the top form, then it's delayed. I trigger the EndEdit on rowvalidation of the gridview..maybe I should also do it just when the bottom form loses focus?

Comment: actually.. it also gets caught if I stay on the edited record in the bottom detail gridview, but then click on another field in the top form, before navigating to the next record in the top form.  So the problem only occurs when I go from an edited bottom record and immediately click the navigate to the next record. Seems like a timing thing?

Comment: seems I am confirming the order of events is not what I expected.. When the user clicks out of the bottom form, i have tried many different events to try and call the EndEdit on it's bindingsource. However, every event seems to only get called AFTER the event that is clicked on in the top form (ie. moving records), which is where I check HasChanges, etc.   The events on the bottom applet that I have tried are:  RowValidating on the grid, Leave on the bottom Form, and CellEndEdit on the grid.  Surprisingly, none of these are called until AFTER the event that is clicked on from the top applet!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was either a general issue with the event orders.. or maybe it's specific to the bindingnavigator or my setup.. but in order to get the bottom form's events firing BEFORE the record is changed in the top applet (when clicking directly from a modified grid row in the bottom, to the navigator), i had to explicitly move focus first in that top applet event.  In my case, i trapped any click on the navigator and just ran this.focus();   that caused all the bottom form events to fire before continuing on.  This then allowed my haschanges() check in the top form to happen after the bindingsource.endedit in the bottom form.